# i keep getting "could not be compiled: unexpected token "{" "

Tags: javascript

ive tried to get this piece of code working but at this time i cant. i tried to read some things about it but still cant figure it out.

```
                            {t = BDV2.WebpackModules.findByUniqueProperties(["isDeveloper"]);
                        Object.defineProperty(t, "isDeveloper", }{
                            get: _ => 1,
                            set: _ => _,
                            BdApi.findModuleByProps("getCurrentUser"){.getCurrentUser().premiumType = 2;},
                            configurable: true,
                            if (.getCurrentUser().premiumType = 0, 1){
                            .getCurrentUser().premiumType = 2;
                            }
                            else {
                            {.getCurrentUser().premiumType = 2;}
                            }
                        });
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

in the line

```
Object.defineProperty(t, "isDeveloper", }{
```

you have a random }.  needs to be

```
Object.defineProperty(t, "isDeveloper", {
```